# display activity countdowntimer in fragment

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I am just starting to learn **Android**, **Java** and need help.
I have an activity with the countdowntimer, which works fine. However, I want it to be displayed in the fragment. What is the best way to do it?
I tried calling `Timer.getCountdowntimer`, I tried calling `Timer.getUserTime` (userTime is the user selected time for the countdowntimer), but the textview in my fragment doesn't display the timer.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding in Java purely, and want to use the android SDK to do it, I would recommend:-

```
//Create a handler that runs on main loop so we can update UX
        final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        //Get a callback in 1 second
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            int timer;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timer += 1;
                myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(timer));
                //Recursively get another callback in a second
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Make sure you add some logic to stop the timer when you want, and also onPause/onResume